# validate element value with attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

`<list count="3">foo bar baz</list>`

Is there any way to check if `list` element contains 3 elements, as it's said in attribute `count`?

Comment: Three **elements** (i.e. tags) or three **words** (text separated with spaces)?

Comment: @potame I meant words. Answer provided by kjhughes works perfectly for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD 1.0 alone cannot enforce this constraint, but **XSD 1.1 can via `xs:assert`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="count" use="required" type="xs:int"/>        
        <xs:assert test="count(tokenize(., ' ')) = @count"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```